# tideman: locked pairs function code CS50 the code is not working for some reason

Tags: c, cs50

```
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        bool isCycle = false;
        int m = i;

        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(j != i)
            {
                if(locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(pairs[j].winner == pairs[m].loser)
            {
                m = j;
                j = -1;
                if(pairs[m].loser == pairs[i].loser)
                {
                    isCycle = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isCycle == false)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

so the code is based on small explanantion by a nicknapoli82 https://gist.github.com/nicknapoli82/6c5a1706489e70342e9a0a635ae738c9

[image: result from check50]

i have tried to dry run the code, with the logic from the below part and the code is working fine for me but it is still giving the error that !! lock pairs skip final pair if it creates a cycle !!

[image: the part that i did a dry run of from the cs50 explanation from https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/3/tideman/]

thanks in advance for any suggestions... :)

My tideman code as of now...

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;
bool glob_false;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name,candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]] += 1;

        }
    }
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if(preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int greatest_num_index = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            int diff_l = preferences[pairs[greatest_num_index].winner][pairs[greatest_num_index].loser] - preferences[pairs[greatest_num_index].loser][pairs[greatest_num_index].winner];
            int diff_j = preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] - preferences[pairs[j].loser][pairs[j].winner];

            if (diff_l < diff_j)
            {
                greatest_num_index = j;
            }
        }
        pair temp = pairs[greatest_num_index];
        pairs[greatest_num_index] = pairs[i];
        pairs[i] = temp;

    }
}

void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        bool isCycle = false;
        int m = i;
        bool doIf;

        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            doIf = true;

            if((j != i) && (locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == false))
            {
                doIf = false;
            }
            if(doIf == true)
            {
                if(pairs[j].winner == pairs[m].loser)
                {
                    m = j;
                    j = -1;
                    if(pairs[m].loser == pairs[i].loser)
                    {
                        isCycle = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(isCycle == false)
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}

// Print the winner of the election
int check_winner(int winning_pair_index)
{
    if(locked[pairs[winning_pair_index].winner][pairs[winning_pair_index].loser] == true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
        {
            if(pairs[winning_pair_index].winner == pairs[i].loser)
            {
                winning_pair_index = i;
                winning_pair_index = check_winner(winning_pair_index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return winning_pair_index;
    }
    return winning_pair_index;
}

void print_winner(void)
{
    int winning_index_pair = check_winner(0);
    string winner = candidates[pairs[winning_index_pair].winner];
    printf("%s", winner);

}
```

i actually changed my code a bit, the previous one would break the inner for loop if it encountered a pair that has not yet been locked, now it just skipp that pair instead, you would understandthe problem by understanding the code a bit. it gives the same errors in check50 none the less. :/

Comment: This is a common question. Type `"[cs50] tideman"` into the search box at the top of the page. There are several ways to approach ensuring a cycle on locking the final pair isn't created. Note the word *final* in the tideman instruction. Also, ensure your candidate votes are sorted as specified in the instructions before you begin locking.

Comment: If you are still stuck, please edit your question to provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How you have handled `pairs` prior to `lock_pairs()` is necessary to see to provide any definitive answer on your code in the question. (that's not to take away from the good effort you put into your question -- it is just incomplete)

Comment: hey, so the final pair is the last pair in the pairs list, as per my understanding check50 is specifically checking for the case similar to the one i have provided [alice, bob, charlie]. here, if the last pair is creating a cycle the it should not be locked, am i right?

Comment: YES -- 100% correct. [Tideman (one approach)](https://pastebin.com/Ep8V4ZZU) If you put your vote data in a file (to save typing -- see bottom of the source file), make sure you define `REDIR` (e.g. add `-DREDIR` to your compile string). Then you can just redirect the contents of the file to the program, e..g `./tideman < yourvotefile.txt`.

Comment: The usage with redirect is `./tideman Alice Bob Charlie < votes.txt` You still need to specify the candidates on the command line.

Comment: You're not really able to help, not to be rude, bur i have already tried a bunch of prompts and votings but the code still says the same error, i.e. lock pair skips the final pair if it creates a cycle, so it's that there is something inherently very wrong with the code or just some case which it is not able to fulfill. that's why i needed your help. Acc. to my testing the skipping the last pair is working fine for the code, but it still gives the same error

Comment: Did you think of adding any of the debug output I show In the code I provided a link to? Doing so makes clear you `sort()` fails to sort in descending order of preference. Fix that first. In fact, your `sort()` doesn't change the order at all.

Comment: The problem actually begins in your `add_pairs()` code, your `sort_pairs()` works fine. After you fix that, your next problem is in `lock_pairs()` - check the order of `locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;` or should that be `locked[pairs[i].loser][pairs[i].winner] = true;` ?? That isn't the only problem - you still place a vote that creates a cycle. Try replacing the `lock_pairs()` with the one from the code I linked. See what the difference is.

Comment: Your print winner will need nested loops (or an unrolled loop) to check each element in `locked` for a candidate. The candidate with no locked edge is the winner.

Comment: Here is your code with a few functions replaced that works [Tideman Bad Parts Fixed](https://paste.opensuse.org/a6b2e4f8caa2) Add `-DDEBUG` with gcc/clang or `/DDEBUG` with VS to turn on additional debug output showing pre and post-sort ordering and the contents of the `locked` matrix.